# Recover partially download file auto deleted by Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome

Where can I find **partially completed** download file (from chrome ) on my system as(chrome and chromium) it **delete them in event of interruption** (NET ISSUE).

I need the file so that I complete download process using wget

The file weigh 1 GB before getting interrupted(NET ISSUE) I happen to download

**825 MB** I dont want to download the 825 MB chunk again

If deleted how can I recover it back .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### How to prevent such loss

Here's a simple script that I use while downloading a bigger file.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ~/partial-download.sh

if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    cp "$1" "${1}.backup"
fi
```

My `crontab` entry then looks like this

```
*/10 * * * * /home/user/partial-download.sh "/home/user/file.crdownload"
```

And continue the partial download using `wget -c`

Comment: Are you sure this work because chrome auto delete the file moment is cancelled something I have already mention in my question and other answer comment

Comment: Sorry for that. My answer is not a recovery script. It's rather a **prevention**. What it does is, that during the download, if the file exists, copy it to `.backup` file, which then can be used as recovery.

Answer (score 1):

In address bar type `chrome://flags`. and search for `Enable Download Resumption`

enable this option, restart your chrome browser and it will do the trick.

Comment: that option was deleted? I cant found in chrome 80++

Answer (score 1):

Zajo's method of preventing is a big waste of writes. Furthermore, imagine the `$1` is big enough to make the `cp` take some time... the previous `$1.backup` will be lost (or partially) if the `$1` is deleted by Chrome. ([see this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6924/what-happens-if-a-file-is-modified-while-youre-copying-it))

A much better way (and a lot easier), to prevent such loss, is just to make a hard link (only once, of course!) as soon as the file.crdownload is created by Chrome:

```
ln file.crdownload file.crdownload.twin
```

(A hard link is just another path to the same file. You just have to delete the link (or the file) at the end of a complete download.)

Comment: Well, I can see another answer here.

Comment: I know... I know this is not a answer to the question. I just wanted to comment the @Zajo method but I can't: I know I need reputation to comment. (My post has been edited to remove these facts, I don't understand why but I don't care). I thought my comment is enough important to be posted...as an answer (since this is the only way I can). As soon as I get enough reputation, I will delete it to post it at the right place: as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome creates files with the extension .crdownload in the chosen download folder.
I'm not sure if the download is linear or if it acts as a torrent download manager that downloads parts randomly till it generates the final file.

Comment: It is probably linear because torrent gets from various different sources.

Comment: Thanks I'm aware of that but its obvious that chrome auto deleted any any uncompleted file instantaneously Here a link for more reference http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28612 . Now recovering that deleted file is what I want. Your assumption is correct that it a linear download that y is suggested in Q that i want to download the remaining part using wget if not linear that would have not been possible plus it single user and single server download scenario unlike torrent

Comment: Could you please answer something that i dont know i.e answer to  that Q

Comment: Oh! Sorry I didn't know that it's a rhetorical question.

Comment: Older file systems are easier to recover from like ext2 ext3 (ext4 probably because it is an improvement of its predecessors). See if it can help you:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-recover-deleted-files-with-lsof-command.html
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/recover-deleted-files-from-your-linux-system/