# How to prevent auto delete partially download file on fail using chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download, chromium

When I download something from the chrome browser (or Chromium, Brave, etc), it's will create a temporary file with extension **.crdownload**. When the download completed it's will be renamed to real file name but if the download failed(internet loss or server down) that file automatically deleted. So how to prevent that happens?

I know there is exists [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/425073/recover-partially-download-file-auto-deleted-by-chrome), that question is to *recover* but the answer is to *prevent*. And unfortunately, the answer is outdated or doesn't work in chrome 80, so I ask again.

I want to use the incomplete file to play or extract it. Because even it's not completed, usually the file still playable(if video) and extractable(if zip/rar). Better get partially file rather than nothing right? And I can redownload or resume using another tool if I need to do it.

I don't like to use the download manager because complicated and it makes slows my computer (I have a slow computer).

I need a solution for all OS(windows, Linux, mac).

Comment: Use a download manager. The file will not be usable to Chrome after and so there is no point to retaining it IF you intend to attempt to restart the download using Chrome. If you intend something else, you need to tell us WHY you need this, because that WHY is going to be key to getting you an answer.

Comment: updated, thank you

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur You really have a professional looking website. I recommend you to resolve the issue that your website shows "â€' instead of " ' " You should add charset UTF-8 in your website headers. :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a workaround for this problem by adding a task to the Windows 10 Task Scheduler that periodically executes a bat that copies all *.crdownload files to a backup folder. This way, if a download fails, you only lose the part since the last task execution (I set mine to repeat every 15 minutes).

I know it's not an ideal solution, but it works ok for my purposes.

First, in Task Scheduler create a new task and set it to 'Run wheter user is logged in or not' and 'Hidden'.
I added a trigger to begin the task 'On a schedule', 'Daily', 'Recur every 1 days'. Repeat task every 15 minutes (or whatever interval you'd like) for a duration of 1 day.
Under 'Actions', I added a 'Start a program' action that runs a .bat with the following content:

```
xcopy *.crdownload .\crdownload_backup /i /y
```

This copies any .crdownload file in the folder where the .bat is to a 'crdownload_backup' subfolder and overwrites any existing files with the same name. Make sure you set the 'Start in' folder in the Settings, so it will execute in the correct folder.

Note: You will have to purge the crdownload_backup folder from time to time, since there is no logic to delete the backup files once a download has completed.